# What is math.comb() used for?

Tags: math, python-3.10

I am having trouble understanding what `math.comb()` is used for.

Could someone explain to me and provide an example please?

Comment: Did you try to read documentation on `math.comb`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb

Comment: Example:  How many ways can you form a team of 2 people from a group of 6 individuals.  Answer: `math.comb(6,2)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.